# How do I get LDAC / aptX working with a Bluetooth device on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 22.04

I've got a few devices that support LDAC or aptX that are using SBC when connected to Bluetooth in Ubuntu. I saw somewhere that PulseAudio should support those in version 15. Ubuntu 22.04 ships with version 15 but it seems to still use SBC. How do I get Ubuntu 22.04 to use LDAC or aptX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The codecs in question are simply not installed by default. If you want them, all you need to do is:

```
sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

A restart is probably needed afterwards.

Comment: I did this and restarted the system. But, the codecs still do not show up in audio options. Only msbc and mcvsd available are there

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put pipewire instead of pulseaudio. It let's you finetune the codec to use in kde settings.
https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e?permalink_comment_id=3976309

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1291012)